# How is GraphQL more efficient than REST?

Tags: rest, graphql

Let's take the SpaceX launches api for example. 
If I make a request with REST (in Node.js) 
It'll look something like this :

```
router.get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches', function (req, res) {
    // What to do with it
})
```

This will get me all launches data.

Now, with GraphQL you specify only the fields you want.

```
const LaunchType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Launch',
  fields: () => ({
    flight_number: { type: GraphQLInt },
    mission_name: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_year: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_date_local: { type: GraphQLString },
    launch_success: { type: GraphQLBoolean },
    rocket: { type: RocketType }
  })
})
```

But.. in the query you supply the same route as the REST version route.

```
resolve(parent, args) {
      return axios
        .get('https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches')
        .then((res) => res.data)
    }
```

So how is the GraphQL request different? doesn't it actually fetch the whole data too?
Can it "traverse" the route somehow when it makes the request?

Comment: I suggest you look into https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql-vs-rest-5d425123e34b and https://www.howtographql.com/basics/1-graphql-is-the-better-rest/ to see the difference, but to answer your question, no, it doesn't fetch everything unless you ask for it. If you're only interested in `flight_number` or `mission_name`, it will only return just that data in the same exact format that you've asked for. `REST` will return everything and you don't know how the data is going to be structured.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the server does in fact fetch the whole response from the underlying REST API. Your `resolve` function is just the function that's called to get the value of a particular field. Whether you call `axios.get` inside a resolver or outside of one doesn't matter -- it's still going to return the same thing.

However, any client making a request to your GraphQL service will have to specify which fields (`flight_number`, `mission_name`, etc.) it wants returned. When the client makes the request, the GraphQL service calls the REST API, gets the full response and then transforms it to reflect the fields requested by the client.

Whether this is more efficient than calling the REST endpoint directly depends on a lot of factors. By only returning the requested fields, a GraphQL response payload may be smaller compared to the "complete" response returned by the REST endpoint. However, GraphQL does add overhead, and having any kind of proxy between your client and the REST API will add latency as well -- that may or may not be offset by any gains from the smaller payload. That said, if you cache the responses from the REST endpoint on your server, you can speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: So, If i'm making a GraphQL to REST request the gain (without considering other factors) should be in the lesser amount of response data i'll send back to my client
from my local server. 
And if I make a GraphQL to GraphQL request than I can get the full potential of 
requesting specific fields. 
I got it right?